# Guava/Otto EventBus with null references

Tags: java, android, guava, event-bus, otto

Suppose the following scenario with classes A,B and an instance of a event bus (It can be the [Guava event bus](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/eventbus/package-summary.html), by Google or the [Otto event bus](http://square.github.io/otto/), by Squ.re)

```
class A{
    @Subscribe
    public void onSomething(B event){
        //do something
    }
}

A a = new A();
eventBus.subscribe(a);
eventBus.post(new B());
// onSomething is called, everything ok

a = null;
eventBus.post(new B());
// onSomething is called again
```

Now, if I run that (only tested with Otto) `onSomething` is called 2 times.

¿Will the event bus hold a reference to '`a`' until unregister is called?

And more importantly

¿If for some reason I am unable to determine the moment in which '`a`' will be null, then the event bus will hold a useless reference to the object forever (memory leak)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The event bus will hold a strong reference always. The answer to both of your questions is yes.

When you set `a` to `null` above you are only clearing the local reference. Both Guava and Otto maintain a strong reference and require explicit unregistration. You will see the above behavior in both event buses.

I strongly suggest you tie the registration of an object to something other than the clearing of a local reference. The Android activity and fragment lifecycle is an obvious choice and so are things like `close` and `destroy`-like methods on individual objects.